# CakePHP Pagination Count Query Not Working

Tags: php, pagination, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.6

Hello I have relationship in User model Like This.

**UserModel**

```
public $hasOne = [
        'Userdetail'  => [
            'className'    => 'Userdetail',
            'foreignKey'   => 'user_id'
        ],
        'Application' => [
            'className'    => 'Application',
            'foreignKey'   => 'user_id'
        ],
    ];
```

I have add extra HasOne Relationship in MyConroller Like below :

**Controller**

```
$this->User->bindModel([
            'hasOne' => [
                'Events' => [
                    'className'  => 'Events',
                    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                    'dependent' => true,
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```

I am create a pagination with the User model like below :

**Pagination**

```
$this->paginate = [
            'conditions' => [
                $this->conditions,
                'Events.id !=' => null
            ],
            'order' => 'User.id DESC'
        ];
```

I don't want that record whose event id is null so I put this in pagination condition. Than i got below error.

```
Unknown column 'Events.id' in 'where clause'
```

Event's model is not reflect in the Count query for the pagination.

Please help me on this concern.

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: `$this->User->bindModel([
 'hasOne' => [
  'Event' => [
   'className'  => 'Events',
   'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
   'dependent' => true,
  ],
  'conditions'=>['Events.id !=' => null,
  ]
 ]
]);` and remove it from `paginate condition`

Comment: No it is CakePhp 2.6

Comment: I try this @Anant but it's not working

Comment: sorry one mistake  `'className' => 'Event'` and `'conditions'=>['Event.id !='`

Comment: Yes it's working but it will retrieve all the data who have not any entry in Event table. I don’t want that records who don't have any events.

Comment: `'conditions'=>['Events.user_id =' => 'User.id' ]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106790/discussion-between-ravs-patel-and-anant).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `false` as a second parameter in `bindModel` to make the changes permanent:

```
$this->User->bindModel([
        'hasOne' => [
            'Events' => [
                'className'  => 'Events',
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                'dependent' => true,
            ]
        ]
    ],false);
```

Otherwise CakePHP will revert to the previously defined relationships in the second query that produces the count, which is different from the first one that retrieves the results.

See [`Model::bindModel()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/class-Model.html#_bindModel)